# Social Tables: Download venue image

Tags: social-tables

Is it possible to access the 120x120 image of the Social Tables venue/bookable room through the API (same image that's displayed in the Venues area of the app)?

I can see urls for images in the response from the Rooms API endpoint, but they present a 'key does not exist' error when accessed. Not sure if these are intended for use by API consumers or not.

```
{
    "id": "cj1i5gi2h05f10fgc0wi6vuwc",
    ...
    "resources": {
        "svgs": {
            "room": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/socialtables-property-service/rooms/cj1i5gi2h05f10fgc0wi6vuwc.svg",
            "withFloor": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/socialtables-property-service/rooms/cj1i5gi2h05f10fgc0wi6vuwc-with-floor.svg"
        },
        "images": {
            "room": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/socialtables-property-service/rooms/cj1i5gi2h05f10fgc0wi6vuwc.png",
            "160x160": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/socialtables-property-service/rooms/cj1i5gi2h05f10fgc0wi6vuwc-160x160.png",
            "withFloor": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/socialtables-property-service/rooms/cj1i5gi2h05f10fgc0wi6vuwc-with-floor-1200x1200.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share the exact endpoint your hitting so i could be of more assistance?

Comment: Certainly https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/properties/cj1i1jffv00870f4jc372uvul/rooms

Comment: I also added the response json with the image URLs that I referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible - the current behavior relates to platform lag on our end.

The images are created asynchronously and eventually uploaded to the URLs indicated on the `4.0/rooms/:room_id` endpoint. Unfortunately, this sometimes means that the image is not yet present in the S3 bucket at request time. We recommend that API consumers poll for the image after creating a new room.

It also appears that we are experiencing significant delays generating the images at this time. We appreciate you bringing the issue to our attention, and are working to churn through the queued image backlog.

Comment: Terrific! This makes sense and will work great. Polling will work just fine. Thanks for working on the backlog.